# Welche Grammatik steckt hinter "habe/hat warten lassen"?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification

Ich habe diese Phrase bereits mehrere Male in Zeitungsartikeln sowie auf Homepages gesehen, bin mir aber nicht ganz sicher, welche Grammatik es ist für "habe warten lassen" bzw. "hat warten lassen".

Ein Beispiel:

> Ich bedauere das Eigeninteresse einiger Mitgliedstaaten, denen es zuzuschreiben ist, daß dieses Abkommen Jahre auf sich **hat warten lassen.**

Die Bedeutung ist mir generell schon klar, aber die Grammatik dazu verstehe ich nicht. Wozu wird das "hat" gebraucht, und nicht "gewartet haben lassen"? Als ich danach gesucht hatte, konnte ich keine Erklärung finden, nur mehr Beispiele.

Comment: Bitte nicht eine unterschiedliche Sprache für eine Frage und die Überschrift verwenden.

Comment: Ich kann mich dem Kommentar von RHa nur anschließen: Wenn die Überschrift und der Hauptteil in unterschiedlichen Sprachen verfasst sind, ist unklar, in welcher Sprache man die Antwort verfassen soll. Ich habe daher die Überschrift ins Deutsche übersetzt.

Comment: Ah, danke dafür. Ursprünglich war die Frage auch auf English gestellt, habe es dann aber geändert..aber vergessen, den Titel anzupassen ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Haben* ist hier ein Hilfsverb und dient dazu, das Perfekt zu *lassen* zu bilden.

Präsens: Das Abkommen lässt auf sich warten.
Präteritum: Das Abkommen ließ auf sich warten.
Perfekt: Das Abkommen hat auf sich warten lassen.

Das *lassen* am Ende des letzten Satzes ist ein [Ersatzinfinitiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv), der hier das Partizip Perfekt ersetzt.

Comment: Okay, danke, das ist etwas verständlicher/einfacher erklärt als die Antwort von Herr Schölnast. Ich werde mir die Grammatik vom Ersatzinfinitiv nochmal genauer durchlesen, und später dann Ihre Antwort akzeptieren!

Answer (score 0):

Aufs Wesentliche gekürzt, lautet der Satz wie folgt:

> Jemandem ist zuzuschreiben, dass etwas auf sich **hat warten lassen.**

Hier ist die Reihenfolge der Verben etwas ungewöhnlich, denn das Wort *»hat«* ist das finite Verb, also jenes Verb, das gebeugt wurde, um mit dem Subjekt (*»etwas«* bzw. *»dieses Abkommen«*) in Zahl (singular/plural) und Person (1., 2. oder 3. Person) übereinzustimmen. Alle anderen Verben sind nicht gebeugt, liegen also in der infiniten Form vor. Und üblicherweise ist in untergeordneten Nebensätzen das finite Verb das letzte Wort dieses Nebensatzes:

> Jemandem ist zuzuschreiben, dass etwas auf sich **warten lassen hat.**

AUs so einem untergeordneten Nebensatz kann man nämlich einen vollständigen Hauptsatz machen, indem man die Konjunktion (*»dass«*) weglässt und das finite Verb hinten entfernt und an die Position 2 vorrückt:

> Etwas **hat** auf sich **warten lassen.**

Damit ist auch klar, dass *»hat«* hier kein Vollverb, sondern ein Hilfsverb ist, dass keine semantische Bedeutung hat, sondern nur aus grammatischen Gründen notwendig ist. Durch seine Existenz wird nämlich klar, dass der Satz im Perfekt steht.

---

In der Frage wurde vorgeschlagen, den Teil *»hat warten lassen«* durch *»gewartet haben lassen«* zu ersetzen. Das sähe dann so aus:

> Ich bedauere das Eigeninteresse einiger Mitgliedstaaten, denen es zuzuschreiben ist, daß dieses Abkommen Jahre auf sich gewartet haben lassen.

bzw. in der abgespeckten Version:

> Jemandem ist zuzuschreiben, dass etwas auf sich **gewartet haben lassen.**

Das ist leider grammatisch falsch. Das finite (durch Beugung an das Subjekt abgepasste) Verb ist hier *»gewartet«.* Würde man es an Position 2 stellen, um einen Hauptsatz zu erhalten, käme dabei das heraus:

> *(falsch!)* Etwas **gewartet** auf sich **haben lassen.**

Wenn ein Vollverb mit einem Hilfsverb kombiniert wird, bleibt das Vollverb immer in seiner infiniten Form und es ist immer das Hilfsverb, dass in eine finite Form wechselt.